# how to instruct gcc/clang to output temporary files to a particular directory

Tags: gcc, command-line, g++, clang, clang++

While using the `--save-temps` option to save the temporary files, gcc/clang outputs the temporary file in the same directory as the input files. Is there an option to instruct gcc to output the files to some other directory.

OR,

When not using the `--save-temps` option the temporary files are created in a default directory (i.e. `$TMPDIR` such as `/tmp`) but they are deleted once the object file is created. Is there a way to instruct the compiler to keep those files instead of just deleting them ( i think that the only option is `--save-temps`, which has the problem stated above)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you use `-save-temps=obj` the temporary files are put in the same directory as the output files, so e.g.

```
gcc -save-temps=obj -o dir/foo.o foo.c
```

will create `dir/foo.i`

This is documented in the manual, obviously. All supported options are listed at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html and that links to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html for `-save-temps`.

Comment: I am using gcc version 4.3.4.
I tried using "=obj" but it gives my error "gcc: unrecognized option '-save-temps=obj'".
The command I fired is "gcc -c -w -save-temps=obj -ggdb -m32 test_code.c -o 32_test/test_code.o".
Any hint to get rid of this error?

Comment: @RupeshKumar, prior to GCC 4.5.0 the `-save-temps` option doesn't accept an argument, so either just use `-save-temps` and the intermediate files will be in the same directory as the input files, or upgrade your compiler (4.3.4 is very old).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the reply. I cannot upgrade the compiler as it may break things. In makefile I used the mv command to move the intermediate files to desired directory.

Comment: The linked page currently makes no mention whatsoever of `-save-temps`.

Comment: @Riot, thanks, it moved to another page. You can still find it via the list of all options.